# Pass a signal in low-level entities and update it back in top-level entity in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, signal

I have tried a lot to pass a signal that is in a top-level entity, to a low-level entity as an in-port and do some operations on that signal and let the changes happen to the main signal.

Here i just used *inc_tb.vhd* (as a top-level module) that has a signal named PC and *inc.vhd* (as a low-level module) that gets the PC and increment it by one at clock edge. But whatever i do, PC gets the 'X' value.
How can i do this?

### This is the inc.vhd (low-level module):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.types.all;

entity inc is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        pc_in : in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
        pc_out : out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behav of inc is
begin
    process(clk) is
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            pc_out <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(pc_in) + 1);
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

### This is the inc_tb.vhd (top-level module):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.types.all;

entity inc_tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of inc_tb is
    -- inputs
    signal pc : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := x"004";
    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
begin
    -- DUT
    CPU_1 : entity work.inc(behav) port map(clk, pc, pc); -- i want this to just increment pc

    -- clock event
    clk <= not clk after 5 ns;

    process is
    begin
        wait for 10*100 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: On Github  see [mano-cpu](https://github.com/susam/mano-cpu) implemented in discrete processes (which could be moved to separate entity/architecture pairs). Before anyone could point it out you deleted [Spliting a process into many entity's in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764740/spliting-a-process-into-many-entitys-in-vhdl) on Stackoverflow. Use a detailed HW block diagram showing ports, create and analyze (compile) the VHDL design hierarchy first, then add processes derived from your original code using signals, not variables. Signals should only be assigned in one process.

Comment: From the comments to the accepted answer this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have an accepted answer that only eliminates one VHDL language usage issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same signal as in- and output.

Don't forget that you're not programming a sequential programming language. In

```
 entity work.inc(behav) port map(clk, pc, pc);
```

The first and second `pc` are actually **the same** wires! (In fact, I'd expect your synthesizer to even complain about `pc` being driven by multiple drivers.)

This might indicate you're not already very familiar with the nonsequential logic of HDLs. Going back and doing a more basic VHDL tutorial might really pay off for you, and save you a lot of time overall.

Comment: thanks for the answer Marcus , i some how know that PC is driven by multiple drivers, but i just want to know how can i update PC in low-level modules and let it be updated in the top-level as well!! i dont know how to do that. could u please help?

Comment: You asking that shows you haven't understood my answer, which means you haven't understood how VHDL works: I really can't answer this any better than: do a beginner's VHDL tutorial. You're trying to use VHDL as sequential language, and it's not. This can't work.

Comment: in other words: what you're trying to do makes no sense, and you'll need tounderstand why it makes no sense if you want to work at this level with VHDL.

Comment: yes i was trying to do that , i thought i could do it, and make my code modular.

Comment: you can make your code modular, that has nothing to do with this.

Comment: i have a code that has, an entity full of signals and one process in just one file i just want to use this trick that i pass those signals to low-level entitys but if i would to pass them they should be passed like this PC in this example.

Comment: as said three times now: this is not how HDLs work.